# How to make sure version is increasing?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, winui-3

I am currently retrieving the app version like this

```
string appVersion = string.Format("Version: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
                    Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.Version.Major,
                    Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.Version.Minor,
                    Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.Version.Build,
                    Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.Version.Revision);
```

Where is this variable written in?

How do I make sure the version is going up on each release?

Is this the correct form?

Answer (score 1):

The version number is defined in the AssemblyInfo.cs in your project's Properties.

If you want to automatically increase the version number every time you build the project you can put in a * instead of a number.

Yes, the version number goes Major, minor, Build, Revision. But just use a system that makes sense for you and your project.

You can read more in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/general/assembly-version-assembly-file-version